# Bound Mismatch : Generic class (of a Generic class extending Comparable (of a Generic class extending Comparable))

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I know it sounds confusing, but that's the best I could explain. (You can suggest a better title). I have 3 classes:-

`A`

```
public class A <T extends Comparable<T>> {
    ...
}
```

`B`

```
public class B {
    A<C> var = new A<C>(); 
    // Bound mismatch: The type C is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T>> of the type A<T>
    ...
}
```

`C`

```
public class C <T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<C>{
    private T t = null;
    public C (T t){
        this.t = t; 
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(C o) {
        return t.compareTo((T) o.t);
    }
    ...
}
```

I am getting an error where I try to instantiate `A` in `B`

Bound mismatch: The type C is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter < T extends Comparable < T > > of the type A

Comment: For one, your `C` is a rawtype in `B`. And also in the `compareTo` method of `C`. There is heavy mixing of rawtypes and generics here - and that is why you have issues.

Comment: Yes but if it implements Comparable, won't it work? Or better yet, is there a way I can make it work?

Comment: No. Because your `C<T>` is only comparable to a rawtype `C`. As I say, you need to do some more reading.

Comment: Gotcha! So say I want Integers to be stored, it should be     `A<C<Integer>> var = new A<C<Integer>(); `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above @Boris the Spider

The problem is that `C` is a raw type in `B`
. Changed the instantiation to include the parameter (depending on the need)

```
A< C<Integer> > var = new A< C<Integer> >();
```

EDIT 1:
Also, thanks to the comment below. A better practice is to change compareTo method in `C` to this,

```
public int compareTo(C<T> o) {
    return t.compareTo(o.t);
}
```

EDIT 2:
Also, there is a typo in the question (w.r.t. comments below)

```
public class C <T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable< C<T> >{...}
```

Comment: You are also using the raw type `C` in `C` itself.

Comment: You're right! Although its not necessary but I did get a warning.

Comment: The other place you use the raw type `C` is `public class C <T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<C>`. It should be `public class C <T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<C<T>>`. If you use raw types some really really weird things can happen, so avoid them at all costs.